# mysql concat from select result

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert data in MySQL with automatic naming on field `username` but how i can do it?.

Currently data at table is:

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin1   |
|  2 | admin2   |
+----+----------+
```

I try using this sql but it's can't:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (
`username`
)
VALUES (
CONCAT('admin',(SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`username`,'admin',-1))+1 FROM `tbl_user`))
);
```

and get error message `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl_user' for update in FROM clause`
Final result i want is:

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin1   |
|  2 | admin2   |
|  6 | admin3   |
|  9 | admin4   |
+----+----------+
```

is that possible? thanks.

Comment: Do you need this every time a new user is inserted, or just for one initial set?  You can use an `UPDATE` to concatenate the `id` with `admin`.

Comment: I won't based on the `id` but MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(username,'admin',-1))+1. Is that possible?

Comment: Just INSERT and then UPDATE, as Michael Berkowski suggests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a trigger that would update the column *username* after an insert. Here's some more information on how to actually do this: http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml

**Edit**

I forgot that MySQL won't allow you to update a table from a trigger declared on the same table.

However, this should do what you're trying to do:

```
SET @id := (SELECT id FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (username) VALUES(
   CONCAT("ADMIN", @id + 1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e321/1)**

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (
`username`
)
VALUES (
CONCAT('admin',(SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(`username`,'admin','') AS SIGNED INTEGER))+1 
                FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_user) t))
);
```

Result:

```
|     ID | USERNAME |
---------------------
|      1 |   admin1 |
|      2 |   admin2 |
| (null) |   admin3 |
```